# How to handle Thrown error in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a piece of code in which multiple promises are being handled using Promise.all, but one of the promise isn't resolving or rejecting but throwing error. Now my question is how to handle this error inside promise.all.

Please note, promises are coming from 3rd party module (node_modules) so i cannot change the code inside the promises, but can only handle the error.

a implementation of above question is

```
try {
  const a = await Promise.all([
    Promise.resolve(1),
    func1()
    // Promise.reject(4),
  ]);

  console.log(a);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("caught", e); // no error caught
}

// suppose func1 is some function exported by 3rd party package
async function func1() {
  return await new Promise((rs, rj) => {
    return setTimeout(() => {
      throw new Error("error");
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Tried many ways like

```
func1().catch(e => e)
```

```
func2(){
  try{ func1() }catch(err){ throw err }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks all for the responses. I couldn't find a possible solution for the above issue so we got the fix from 3rd party package. As many pointed out, the fix of implementation of func1 was the only quick solution for now to resolve the above issue.

Comment: Make sure to invoke _either_ the `resolve` or `reject` callbacks.

Comment: throwing an error inside the setTimeout does not reject the Promise - your contrived `func1` is not useful at all for the purpose

Comment: "*the promise isn't resolving or rejecting*" - then `Promise.all` cannot handle it. Fix the implementation of `func1` not to crash. If it's a third party, file a bug report and prepare a patch. This is more annoying of course but there's nothing else you can do.

Comment: @JaromandaX per the `// suppose`  comment in the post, promises returned by `func1` calls are being used to exemplify the bad behavior of 3rd party promises whose processing globally throws errors without also rejecting the promise involved.

Comment: @traktor - no idea

Answer (score 0):

You should use `reject` callback in a promise constructor explicitly, otherwise your error is thrown in another JS macrotask, not affecting the promise.

Given that an async function rejects a promise properly `Promise.all` works as expected:

```js
// suppose func1 is some function exported by 3rd party package
function func1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("my promise error")), 1000));
}

(async () => {
  
  try{
    await Promise.all([func1()]);
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e.message);
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

At the time  ES6 promises were introduced, there was no such thing as an uncaught rejection error because errors could be left in rejected state as long as you wanted, and throwing an error inside a promise handler simply rejected the promise passed to the next promise in a chain (if there was one).

To force error reporting, (some) developers adopted to use a  timeout to throw the error in the code's global context:

```
setTimeout( (error => throw error), error, 0);
```

This prevents promise reaction jobs (run from the microtask queue) from detecting the error when executing user provided promise handler functions.

How this would leave the promise accessed by your code pending is unknown - but provision of the promise, possibly at the end of a promise chain, seems to have managed.

**Workaround**

1. Listen for global errors and promisify receiving one.
2. Run Promise.all normally
3. Pass the promises returned in 1 and 2 to Promise.race
4. Finally remove the listener added in 1.

This is not an ongoing fix - the approach *assumes* the error is thrown by the dodgy promise provider, which is not proven, *and* any global error will trigger the workaround, *and* steps should be taken to get the badly behaving promise code code updated- modern browsers report details of uncaught rejection error in detail.

As an example for when the global object is `window`, to use instead of `Promise.all`:

const allOrError = ( ...args) => {

```
let errorHandler = null;
const createHandler = reject => (event => reject(event.error));
return Promise.race(
        Promise.all( ...args),
        new Promise( (res, rej) => { // stays pending or is rejected
            errorHandler = createHandler (rej);
            window.addEventListener("error", errorHandler);
        })
    )
    .finally( 
        ()=> window.removeEventListener("error", errorHandler)
    );
};
```